# html href interacting with javascript in jsp's

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to figure out what exactly this href is doing.  I know href is known to direct the user to a link of some sort.  In this case I need a type of functionality added without using onclick for a button and there is a confusing href in relation to this.

```
href="javascript:formSubmit(document.randomForm, 'main', '/documents/project/open')"
```

Answer (score 0):

An href can also be used to trigger a javascript function when the link is clicked, it is pretty common.

In your case, I cannot tell exactly what 'formSubmit' function does, but if I have to guess, I would think that it submits `document.randomForm`, puts the response HTML into a div with id `main` and `/documenys/project/open` might be the remote URL to where submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided calls the `formSubmit` method,which is Javascript. If I had to make a guess, when you click the hyperlink, a form is submitted.

An example of a simple submitForm method could be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Obviously there is more functionality involved in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When the link is clicked it runs the `formSubmit()` function defined somewhere else in the page's javascript.